# Openstreetmap in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Can we use Openstreetmap in Flutter or can we only use Google Maps?
I wanted to get another way to display a Map. Cause when using googlemaps api key they need to know a Credit Card and i dont have one.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the below plugin. An example is included in the repository.

https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_map

Pub.dev link:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map

Answer (score 5):

You may check out the below Flutter Maps widget which allows you to render tiles from services like OpenStreetMaps which does not require billing.

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_maps

OpenStreetMaps may be used free of cost. However, I would recommend you to check the licensing terms on their official website and ensure it.

Comment: The license is more about the application of copyrights to the open licensed works (the requirement to give the correct credits to OpenStreetMap) which is important but more relevant here is the "Tile Usage Policy" https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/  . It's not really recommended to make an app which sends traffic to the central volunteer funded OpenStreetMap. If your app gets popular, it will be blocked. But there's a few alternative tile servers still based on OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: @HarryWood is it allowed to self-host the OpenStreetMap dataset and point the traffic to your own server if the app becomes popular? If so, it's very safe to develop against OSM servers and just swap a URL to point towards your own infrastructure for production, assuming that is in line with OSM's licensing terms.

Comment: @jdevries3133 Yes. It is *encouraged* to self-host the OpenStreetMap dataset on your own server. You can even apply "diffs" every minute to keep your copy in sync. But whether any of that would be necessary depends on how much tile traffic you're generating. I see flutter generates images with OSM tiles as a background. Maybe it will do a lot of caching to avoid tile traffic anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Declare these dependencies in your *pubspec.yaml*

```
  era_geojson: "^0.1.1+4"
  latlong: "^0.5.3"
```

Then you can write your custom map like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomMap extends CustomPainter {
  Size screenSize;
  List<Offset> pointsRoads;
  List<Offset> pointsBuilding;
  List<Path> pointsBuildings;
  final bgColor = const Color(0xFFF7F7F7);
  final borderColor = const Color(0xFFCBCBCB);
  final buildingColor = const Color(0xFFEFEFEF);
  double scale = 1.0;
  Offset delta = Offset.zero;

  final Paint paintRoads = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.white
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..strokeWidth = 3.0;
  final Paint paintBorder = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black12
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..strokeWidth = 4.0;

  final Paint paintBuilding = Paint()
    ..color = Color(0xFFEFEFEF)
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..strokeWidth = 1.0;

  final Paint paintBuildingBorder = Paint()
    ..color = Color(0xFFEFEFEF)
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..strokeWidth = 1.0;

  CustomMap(
      {this.delta,
      this.scale,
      this.pointsRoads,
      this.pointsBuilding,
      this.pointsBuildings,
      this.screenSize});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.translate(delta.dx, delta.dy);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);
    canvas.drawColor(bgColor, BlendMode.color);
    // Roads Start
    if (pointsRoads != null && pointsRoads.length > 0) {
      var start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      for (int i = 0; i < pointsRoads.length - 1; i++) {
        if (isInScreen(pointsRoads[i], pointsRoads[i + 1])) {
          canvas.drawLine(pointsRoads[i], pointsRoads[i + 1], paintBorder);
        }
      }
      var end = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      print("Draw Roads Border: ${end - start}");

      var start2 = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      for (int i = 0; i < pointsRoads.length - 1; i++) {
        if (isInScreen(pointsRoads[i], pointsRoads[i + 1])) {
          canvas.drawLine(pointsRoads[i], pointsRoads[i + 1], paintRoads);
        }
      }
      var end2 = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      print("Draw Roads: ${end2 - start2}");
    }
    // Roads End

    // Buildings Start
    var start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsBuildings.length - 1; i++) {
      canvas.drawPath(pointsBuildings[i], paintBuilding);
    }
    var end = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Draw Buildings: ${end - start}");

    if (pointsBuilding != null && pointsBuilding.length > 0) {
      var start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      for (int i = 0; i < pointsBuilding.length - 1; i++) {
        if (isInScreen(pointsBuilding[i], pointsBuilding[i + 1])) {
          canvas.drawLine(
              pointsBuilding[i], pointsBuilding[i + 1], paintBuildingBorder);
        }
      }
      var end = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      print("Draw Buildings Border: ${end - start}");
    }
    // Buildings End
  }

  bool isInScreen(Offset first, Offset second) {
    if (first != null && second != null) {
      first = first.scale(scale, scale);
      second = second.scale(scale, scale);
      if ((first.dx > -1 &&
              first.dy > -1 &&
              first.dx < this.screenSize.width &&
              first.dy < this.screenSize.height) ||
          (second.dx > -1 &&
              second.dy > -1 &&
              second.dx < this.screenSize.width &&
              second.dy < this.screenSize.height)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomMap oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

and use it in a wrapping GestureDetector like this:

```
GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              _delta = _delta + details.delta;
            });
          },
          child: CustomPaint(
              painter: CustomMap(
                  scale: _scale,
                  delta: _delta,
                  pointsRoads: _roadsPoints,
                  pointsBuilding: _buildingPoints,
                  pointsBuildings: _pointsBuildings,
                  screenSize: screenSize),
              size: Size.infinite) // CustomPaint
          )
```

See this complete example: https://github.com/aoinakanishi/flutter-openstreetmap-example