# How to use OpenStreetMaps on flutter

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap

Can we use Openstreetmap in Flutter or can we only use Google Maps? I wanted to get another way to display a Map. Cause when using googlemaps api key they need to know a Credit Card and i dont have one.

Comment: Simular question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842695/openstreetmap-in-flutter

Answer (score 5):

You can install this package [flutter_maps](https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map) to use OpenStreetMaps

Here is an example

```
new FlutterMap(
        options: new MapOptions(
            center: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
            zoom: 5.0,
            maxZoom: 5.0,
            minZoom: 3.0),
        layers: [
          new TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate:
                  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
        ],
      ),
```